# Scraping Google Business Phone Numbers

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to build an executable app that scrapes business phone numbers for a number of business (50-100) every day that are in a pandas df. Since I want to make an executable, I want to write the code in python without using selenium web driver, but am unable to figure out any other way to get the phone number values. An example query is: https://www.google.com/search?q=THE+ICE+PALACE+1+MAIN+WALK+CHERRY+GROVE+NY+phone&client=safari&rls=en&hotel_occupancy=2&sxsrf=APwXEdeeern3D6cq4vuQI9grx6ZAj_V9bA%3A1682819400747&ei=SMlNZKuKLYue5NoPwJSr2A8&ved=0ahUKEwirzujkvtD-AhULD1kFHUDKCvsQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=THE+ICE+PALACE+1+MAIN+WALK+CHERRY+GROVE+NY+phone&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCAAQogQyBQgAEKIEMgUIABCiBDIFCAAQogQyCAgAEIkFEKIEOgoIABBHENYEELADSgQIQRgAUOACWOACYN4KaAJwAXgAgAFuiAFukgEDMC4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

And the xpath that I would want to retrieve is: //*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a/span

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

I have tried using the lxml tree function, which has not resulted in returning any values. I know that the xpath is correct and works because it returns the right value when using chromedriver, but would like to do it without chromedriver. Could it possibly be an issue of the fact that the page does not load fully and therefore there is no html returned?

Comment: Have you tried using Google Search API? Or any other Google python library to get results without a browser?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Google My Business Phone Number Selector]

[image: Only One Output]

The Selector is ".mw31Ze". There is only one output. If it doesn't help you then you might use JS for scraping.
It'll be relatively easy to use JS for webscraping.

The selector might be changed if you load mobile version of the page. I had got it previously scraping with python.